# eclipse auto highlight unreadable

Tags: eclipse, highlight, contrast

I have imported a project for an assignment and eclipse has decided to auto highlight parts which make them unreadable. I have looked in the text editor settings and found nothing matching this.

[image: some code highlighted in green, some code highlighted in red]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that output because you (probably accidentally) selected **Coverage As > Java Application** instead of **Run As > Java Application** from the context menu for your project node in **Project Explorer**.

Note that **Coverage As** is immediately above **Run As** in the context menu.

The colors in the output of your screen shot are meaningful:

- A green background means that the code was executed when your application ran.
- A red background means that the code was not executed when your application ran.
- You can also see a yellow background which means that the code was executed but not all possible paths were executed. You might see this on an if statement or a switch statement.

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-code-coverage-in-eclipse) gives a brief summary of code coverage in Eclipse.