# How do I turn off yellow highlighting on code

Tags: java, eclipse

I somehow accidentally turned on some sort of highlighting. All the code inside the methods is getting highlighted to the point where it's unreadable. How do I toggle this off?

[image]

Comment: Might be a code coverage tool.

Comment: I was about to instinctively say that you shouldn't post images of code, but then I read the question.

Comment: In addition, the unreadable indicates that you are using an outdated version. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: I agree with @shmosel that this probably relates to code coverage, which you may have turned on unintentionally when running your application. See [Clearing coverage highlighting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112561/clearing-coverage-highlighting-in-eclipse) for details on turning it off. Also, though not a duplicate, [eclipse auto highlight unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50580809/2985643) may be helpful.